# What end point should I be using to integrate the Paysafe Cards API?

Tags: netbanx-api, paysafe

I am trying to invoke a cards api and want to figure out which one I should be calling for the different responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what you are using in order to process credit cards. But the below endpoints should be good enough to get you going in the right direction.

**Direct Debit (eChecks)**

For Example:
https://api.test.paysafe.com/directdebit/v1/accounts/{ACCOUNT_ID}

**3D Secure (Verified by Visa, SecureCode, or Secure Key)**

For example:
https://api.test.paysafe.com/threedsecure/v1/accounts/{ACCOUNT_ID}

**Profile Management (Rebilling or tokenization)**

For example:
https://api.test.paysafe.com/customervault/v1/profiles/{PROFILE_ID}

**Card Payments (Server to Server Proceessing API - Non Hosted)**

For example:
https://api.test.paysafe.com/cardpayments/v1/accounts/{ACCOUNT_ID}

**Hosted API (Hosted Solution)**

For Example: 
https://api.test.netbanx.com/hosted/v1/orders

For more information, you can always go to the developer center and all of the information is there.

https://developer.paysafe.com/

Hope that this helps!